# Crashlytics is reporting to Fabric but no traces are available in Firebase Crashlytics

Tags: android, firebase, crashlytics

I'm developing a new application and I've successfully registered it into Firebase, and connected the Crashlytics service through the implementation guide (it worked, the app is connected).

My problem is that I'm not able to see any crash traces in the Firebase console, although I can see them correctly in the Fabric console.

Maybe that's the issue, because I'm also using Fabric to distribute the app through the Beta service, so I have the Fabric API Key and initialize the Fabric service just for Beta. In this scenario, no crashes are sent to any plattform, neither Firebase nor Fabric.

build.gradle

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.28.1'
```

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.8'
implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.9'
```

Application:

```
final Fabric fabric = new Fabric.Builder(this)
                .kits(new Beta())
                .debuggable(BuildConfig.DEBUG)
                .build();
        Fabric.with(fabric);
```

What I'm trying to achieve is to receive the crash reports in my Firebase console and not in the Fabric dashboard.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks. Please unlink your app from Firebase and then follow the linking flow. Be sure to leave in your Fabric ap

> You can unlink by using the following URL: https://fabric.io/remove_firebase_crashlytics?clientId=CLIENT_ID&projectId=PROJECT_ID

CLIENT_ID is your Firebase app client id
PROJECT_ID is your app’s containing Firebase project

For example, with these values:
clientId: ios:com.remove.crashlytics.1
projectId: test-removing-crashlytics

The link becomes: https://fabric.io/remove_firebase_crashlytics?clientId=ios:com.remove.crashlytics.1&projectId=test-removing-crashlytics

Answer (score 1):

You might forgot to add

**`apply plugin: 'io.fabric'`** and

**`apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'`** in build.gradle(app-level).

EXAMPLE for:

**build.gradle(app-level):**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

dependencies {
     ...
     implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:16.0.8'
     ...
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

**build.gradle(project-level):**

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.28.0'
        classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8' // for import error
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

For more info. kindly have a look at [this artical.](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started#android)

You will find crashes in [Firebase console.](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/crashlytics)